# error handling not catching error when reason is given discord.js mute

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I made a mute command and I am having trouble handling an error that is thrown by the 'ms' npm package when I dont give a mute reason it works fine, it handles the error properly but when I do give a reason it logs the error and Doesn't handle it like its supposed to I do not know the reason of this and couldn't find a fix online

here is my code;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    commands: 'mute',
    minArgs: 1,
    maxArgs: null,
    description: 'Mutes a member so that they can no longer type nor speak in text or voice channels',
    info: new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Mute Command')
    .setColor('#6DCE75')
    .setDescription('Use this command to Mute a member so that they cannot chat in text channels nor speak in voice channels')
    .addFields(
      { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=mute (user) (reason)\n=mute (user) (time) (reason)'},
      { name: '**Example:**', value: '=mute @Michael stfu\n =mute @Michael 1d ur gay'},
      { name: '**Info**', value: 'You cannot mute yourself.\nYou cannot mute me.\nYou cannot mute members with a role higher than yours'}
   )
    .setFooter("Pepe's Helper command help"),
    callback: async (message, args, text, client) => {
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **I do not have Permission to Mute members**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **I do not have Permission to Manage roles**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        const target = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);

         const Embedhelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
         .setTitle('Mute Command')
         .setColor('#6DCE75')
         .setDescription('Use this command to Mute a member so that they cannot chat in text channels nor speak in voice channels')
         .addFields(
           { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=mute (user) (reason)\n=mute (user) (time) (reason)'},
           { name: '**Example:**', value: '=mute @Michael stfu\n =mute @Michael 1d ur gay'},
           { name: '**Info**', value: 'You cannot mute yourself.\nYou cannot mute me.\nYou cannot mute members with a role higher than yours'}
        )
         .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
 
        let reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
        if (!reason) reason = 'No reason Provided'
        const ErrorEmbed7 =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **There was a problem setting permissions for all the channels**')
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        const ErrorEmbed9 =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **There was a problem while creating the muted role.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided';
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
        if (!target) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **Invalid User ID**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'))
        let botrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Pepe's Helper");
        if (target.roles.highest.position > botrole.position) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **My role is not high enough to manage that user, please move my role up the role heiarchy in order to let me manage them.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        if (target.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **That user is a Mod/Admin I cannot manage them.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'))
        if (target.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **You cannot mute yourself.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        if (target.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **You cannot mute me.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        if (target.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === 'Muted')) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **That user is already muted**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
        if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= target.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(':no_entry: **You do not have permission to mute that user, as they have a higher role than you.**')
        .setColor('#FF0000'));
            try {
             let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === 'Muted');
             if (typeof muterole === "undefined") {
                message.guild.roles.create({
                    data: {
                        name: 'Muted',
                        color: '7e7e7e',
                        permissions: []
                    },
                    reason: 'to mute people',
                })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed9)))
                    .then((newmuterole => {
                      target.roles.add(newmuterole)
                      .then(() => {
                        message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setDescription(':white_check_mark: **Successfully Muted '+target.user.tag+' for ``'+reason+'`` '+ms(ms(args[1]))+'**')
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log(err)
                        })
                        .setColor('#0ef606'))
                        .then(target.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle('**You have been Muted in:** '+message.guild.name)
                        .setDescription('**Reason for mute:** ``'+reason+'``\n**Duration:** '+ms(ms(args[1])))
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log(err)
                        })
                        .setColor('#6DCE75')
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())))
                        .catch(err => {
                          console.log(err)
                        })
                      })
                      .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err); 
                        return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setDescription(':no_entry: **I was unable to mute that user.**')
                        .setColor('#FF0000'));
                         })
                      message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
                        try {
                            channel.updateOverwrite(newmuterole, {
                                SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                                SPEAK: false,
                                ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                                READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
                            });
                        } catch (err) {
                          message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed7)
                        };
                })
                setTimeout( function () {
                    target.roles.remove(newmuterole)
                }, ms(args[1]))
             }))
         } else {
            target.roles.add(muterole)
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err); 
              return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription(':no_entry: **I was unable to mute that user.**')
              .setColor('#FF0000'));
               })
            .then(() => {
              message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription(':white_check_mark: **Successfully Muted '+target.user.tag+' for ``'+reason+'`` '+ms(ms(args[1]))+'**')
              .setColor('#0ef606'))
              .then(target.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('**You have been Muted in:** '+message.guild.name)
              .setDescription('**Reason for mute:** ``'+reason+'``\n**Duration:** '+ms(ms(args[1])))
              .setColor('#6DCE75')
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())))
            })
            message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
              try {
                  channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, {
                      SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                      SPEAK: false,
                      ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                      READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
                  });
              } catch (err) {
                message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed7)
              };
      })
      setTimeout( function () {
          target.roles.remove(muterole)
      }, ms(args[1]))
    }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
    if (error instanceof Error) {
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided'
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === 'Muted');
    if (typeof muterole === "undefined") {
       message.guild.roles.create({
           data: {
               name: 'Muted',
               color: '7e7e7e',
               permissions: []
           },
           reason: 'to mute people',
       })
           .catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed9)))
           .then((newmuterole => {
             target.roles.add(newmuterole)
             .then(() => {
              message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription(':white_check_mark: **Successfully Muted '+target.user.tag+' for ``'+reason+'``**')
              .setColor('#0ef606'))
              .then(message.target.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('**You have been Muted in:** '+message.guild.name)
              .setDescription('**Reason for mute:** ``'+reason+'``\n**Duration:** Permanent')
              .setColor('#6DCE75')
              .setTimestamp()
              .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())))
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err); 
              return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setDescription(':no_entry: **I was unable to mute that user.**')
              .setColor('#FF0000'));
               });
             message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
               try {
                   channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, {
                       SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                       SPEAK: false,
                       ADD_REACTIONS: false,
                       READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
                   });
               } catch (err) {
                 message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed7)
               };
       })
    }))
} else {
   target.roles.add(muterole)
   .catch(err => {
    console.log(err); 
    return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(':no_entry: **I was unable to mute that user.**')
    .setColor('#FF0000'));
    })
   .then(() => {
    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(':white_check_mark: **Successfully Muted '+target.user.tag+' for ``'+reason+'``**')
    .setColor('#0ef606'))
    .then(target.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('**You have been Muted in: '+message.guild.name)
    .setDescription('**Reason for mute:** ``'+reason+'``\n**Duration:** Permanent')
    .setColor('#6DCE75')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL())))
  })
   message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => {
     try {
         channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, {
             SEND_MESSAGES: false,
             SPEAK: false,
             ADD_REACTIONS: false,
             READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true
         });
     } catch (er) {
       message.channel.send(ErrorEmbed7)
     };
})
}
} else {
    message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(':no_entry: **I was unable to mute that user.**')
    .setColor('#FF0000'))
}
  }
    },
    permissions: 'MUTE_MEMBERS',
    requiredRoles: []
}
```

this code tries to mute the target with a timeout using the 'ms' npm package, but if the given time amount is invalid it catches the error that is thrown by the 'ms' npm package (error is thrown due to invalid time amount) and then instead perm mutes the user and sets that 'inavlid time amount' as the reason, the problem is the error catching only works when there is no time amount given, if the time amount **is given** and **is invalid** then it for some reason doesn't handle the error

if you did not understand my problem please let me know and I will try to explain better.

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's so much code to look for and will hinder others trying to help you. I highly doubt *all of that code* is related to your specific issue.

Comment: What exactly is the error?